# Magento changing product image when option from dropdown is selected

Tags: image, magento

I have been trying to change a configurable product image when an option from dropdown is select using the list.phtml file. Is this possible without using an extension?

Comment: first i need to conform that on which page you are using to change image. On product detail page or product listing page. you have described here list.phtml, so it must be product listing page. however magento dose not provide any dropdown on product listing page. can you please explain in more detail or attach a screenshot please.

Comment: I can not attach a screenshot here but it is in the product view and I have hacked the code to display a drop down in the product view